# phonegap read and write json file

Tags: javascript, json, cordova

I am looking to store a JSON file locally on IOS/Android in a Phonegap(Cordova) application.

Basically, I retrieve a JSON file from the server ($.GETJSON) and I want to first store the JSON file and then retrieve and modify it.

I've looked at FileWriter but I don't see a mimetype... the only example gives text files.

Thanks in advance!

Nick

Comment: why do you need mime type to store json? the data in this case will be stored in a plain text formate only

Answer (score 13):

Nick, just use [FileWriter.write](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter_write_quick_example) to save your JSON data to disk. JSON is a text based file anyway so there is no need to set the mime type. When you are ready to load the file again use [FileReader.readAsText](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileReader_read_as_text). In your "onloadend" handler of the FileReader the method will be called with an event and event.target.result will be your JSON data. Then you'll do a

```
var myJson = JSON.parse(event.target.result);
```

to turn the text into a JSON object.

Comment: for some reason event.target.result gives me not plain 'json' file but with \r\n at each line and JSON.parse fails on that. How to deal with that?

Comment: When saving, use JSON.stringify(yourJsonData);

Answer (score 2):

(for template or default settings) I just store them in seperate constant files so i don't have to use any special file utility addons or commands, super easy:

```
(function(){
angular.module('app').constant('settings_json', 
{  
    "name":"settings",
    "data":[  
       {  
          "set":"globals",
          "share_diagnostics":true,
          "user_prefs_save_cloud": true         
       },
       {
          "set":"user",
          "fname":'',
          "lname": '',
          "telephone": '',
          "email": ''       
       }
    ]
}
)})();
```

Then in your app: (after injecting 'settings_json')

```
var settings = angular.fromJson(settings_json);
```